# Serialize parent-child object

Tags: java, json, rest, serialization, spring-mvc

I have a REST service, built with spring-mvc:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
    <property name="contentType" value="text/plain"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">  
    <property name="messageConverters">  
        <util:list id="beanList">  
            <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>  
        </util:list>  
    </property>  
</bean>
```

To avoid circular references in serialization I annotate the object as follows:

```
class Parent implements Serializable {
    int parent_id;
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Child> children; 
}

class Child implements Serializable {
    int child_id;
    @JsonBackReference
    private Parent parent;
}
```

My REST service exposes two "methods" that gets a parent and a child, respectively:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/parent/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody public Parent getParent(@PathVariable int id , Model model) {
    Parent parent = myManager.getParent(id);
    return parent;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/child/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody public Child getChild(@PathVariable int id , Model model) {
    Child child = myManager.getChild(id);
    return parent;
}
```

The first method, getParent, works as expected and returns a Parent, complete with all children, but the second method, getChild, returns a single child, which does **not** have any reference back to it's parent.

```
json for parent: {"parent_id": 1, "children": [{"child_id":1},{"child_id":2}]}    
json for child: {"child_id":1}
```

So my question is, how do I set up serialization, so that getChild returns some sort of reference to it's parent object?

Comment: do want a reference to the parent, or the actual parent object?

Comment: I would prefer the actual object. Problem is, how to represent the children...

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by upgrading to Jackson 2.0 and Spring 3.1.2 (which adds support for jackson 2.0).

I now annotate the classes like this:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@parentId")
class Parent implements Serializable {
    int parent_id;
    private List<Child> children; 
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@childId")
class Child implements Serializable {
    int child_id;
    private Parent parent;
}
```

and updated servlet-context to use `MappingJackson2JsonView` and `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`

First reference to parent or child contains all info about the object, while any subsequent reference, will only print the id (@childId or @parentId)